# Excel file to pull book titles from a list of ISBN Numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I;m trying to pull book titles from google and have some code - it is just not running correctly and keeps giving errors.I reckon its something simple i just canlt see it  :-)

see code....  tried various ways if pulling this into excel but i need to be able to paste ISBN's into col A and see the results in Col B

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim jsonBooks As Object, auth, authInfo As Object, k
    Dim jsonBook As Object, bookDetails As Object
Set cell_range = Range("A1:A10")
    
For Each cell In cell_range
    Set jsonBooks = BookInfo(ActiveSheet.Cells(r, "A").Value)
    
    'Note: the aPI only returns `{}` if there's no match to
    '      the ISBN, not (eg) status=404
    If Not jsonBooks Is Nothing Then
        If jsonBooks.Count = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "No results"
        Else
            For Each k In jsonBooks
                Debug.Print "-------" & k & "----------"
                Set jsonBook = jsonBooks(k)
                Set bookDetails = jsonBook("details")
                Debug.Print "Title:", bookDetails("title")
                Debug.Print "Pub. Date:", bookDetails("publish_date")
                For Each auth In bookDetails("authors")
                    Debug.Print "Author:", auth("name")
                Next auth
            Next k
          End If
         End If
Next

     End Sub


Function BookInfo(ISBN) As Object
    Dim url As String
    url = "https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:" & ISBN & "&jscmd=details&format=json"
    Set BookInfo = responseObject(url)
End Function

Function responseObject(url As String) As Object
    Dim json As Object, http As Object
    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        'Debug.Print .Status, .responseText
        If .Status = 200 Then
            'Set responseObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 3) = .responseText
        Else
            Debug.Print .responseText, .Status
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Have you debugged your code? What is r in your code? Why do you loop over _cell_range_ if you don't use it?

Comment: tried to debug - not sure why R is in there - it was some elses suggestion...

Comment: Have you tested the initially code you got from someone? Had it worked? Please try `BookInfo(cell)` instead of using ActiveSheet.Cells. Is there a reason why you have removed the JsonConverter in your code?

Comment: the original code was only looking for 1 x ISBN that was within the code itself... i'm trying to make it read the column and then retrive the data cell by cell...  so yes the original worked but wasnlt exactly what i wanted.  Not sure why the Json converter is removed...   i have played around with this all ways and just can't get it to do what i want...  :-(     any ideas.??                                         I've put this instead now           
 Set jsonBooks = BookInfo(cell).Value                still doesn't run....

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim jsonBooks As Object, auth, authInfo As Object, k
    Dim jsonBook As Object, bookDetails As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet, isbn, rngIsbn As Range, cell As Range
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Books")
    
    Set rngIsbn = ws.Range("A1:A5")
    
    For Each cell In rngIsbn
        isbn = cell.Value
        If Len(isbn) > 5 Then
            Set jsonBooks = BookInfo(isbn)
        
            'Note: the aPI only returns `{}` if there's no match to
            '      the ISBN, not (eg) status=404
            If Not jsonBooks Is Nothing Then
                If jsonBooks.Count = 0 Then
                    Debug.Print "No results"
                Else
                    For Each k In jsonBooks
                        Debug.Print "-------" & k & "----------"
                        Set jsonBook = jsonBooks(k)
                        Set bookDetails = jsonBook("details")
                        Debug.Print "Title:", bookDetails("title")
                        Debug.Print "Pub. Date:", bookDetails("publish_date")
                        For Each auth In bookDetails("authors")
                            Debug.Print "Author:", auth("name")
                        Next auth
                    Next k
                  End If
            End If
        End If 'have something to look up
    Next cell

End Sub

Function BookInfo(isbn) As Object
    Dim url As String
    url = "https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:" & isbn & "&jscmd=details&format=json"
    Set BookInfo = responseObject(url)
End Function

Function responseObject(url As String) As Object
    Dim json As Object, http As Object
    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .Send
        'Debug.Print .Status, .responseText
        If .Status = 200 Then
            Set responseObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
        Else
            Debug.Print .responseText, .Status
        End If
    End With
End Function
```